# how can i disable access a property of a object ? JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, properties

how can i disable access a property of a object in JavaScript?
disable read of property

```
    let obj = {
       name: "karl"
    }

    Object.DefineProperty(obj,'name',{
       enumerable: false, 
       writable: false,
       configurable: false
    }

    console.log(obj.name) // karl
```

my goal is to access the property (name) through of a get.
I want to replace the native access of a property with a get, also the assignment and that goes through a custom set

example

```
    let obj = {
       name: "karl",
       get getname()
       {
            return this.name + 2;
       }
    }

    console.log(obj.name) // karl2
```

if the get has the equals name of the property it cause a error 
I can't get it to natively go through the get.

Object.defineProerty does not have a property read property

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the existing value, then reconfigure the property to be a getter:

```js
const obj = {
  name: "karl"
}
const origName = obj.name;
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'name', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  get() {
    return origName + 2;
  }
});

console.log(obj.name) // karl
```

Answer (score 1):

Native set and get functions can be overloaded using Object.defineProperty

```
const obj = {}
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'name', {
  enumerable : false,
  configurable : false,
  set: function (v){name=v;},
  get: function (){return name+2;}
});
obj.name="karl";
console.log(obj.name); // karl2
console.log(obj);      // {} name will not be shown
```

Hope this helps you